# Why do I need to allow `All TCP` in my EC2 security group for me to access my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a rails server running in an EC2 instance and I started the server with `bundle exec rails server --binding=0.0.0.0`. Can someone explain why I need to allow this in my EC2 security group before I can access the site?

`All TCP TCP 0 - 65535 0.0.0.0/0`

Previously, I already have `HTTP`, `SSH`, and `HTTPS` in my security group for both inbound and outbound. I'd expect that when I access the site using `http://ec2-public-ip:3000`, having `HTTP` in inbound/outbound will be sufficient.

In addition to the explanation, what rule should I add so that I can avoid allow `All TCP` in my security group? I assume that is bad practice?

Thank you,
Oky Sabeni

Answer (score 0):

That security group rule opens all TCP traffic on all ports. You are using a non-standard port of `3000` and you haven't explicitly opened that port in any other security group rule. If you changed that to `All TCP TCP 3000 0.0.0.0/0` it would work without opening up all the other ports on the server to Internet traffic.

Your other rules opened the following ports:

```
SSH: 22
HTTP: 80
HTTPS: 443
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm just curious, wouldn't http://ec2-public-ip:3000 mean you are connecting on port 3000? By default HTTP is 80, HTTPS 443, and SSH is 22.

The 0.0.0.0/0 just means you will allow any address to connect.

Comment: It means that Rails is connecting on port 3000. See this ```bundle exec rails server --binding=0.0.0.0
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000```. This may explain it further: http://annaershova.github.io/blog/2015/10/26/what-about-localhost-3000/

Comment: @okysabeni actually it means rails is *"listening"* on port `3000`. That's a non-standard port for `http` traffic.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for letting me know.